# nice ssh2 in php

Tags: php, ssh

I have a php script that transfers a bunch of files between servers with the pecl `ssh2` extension (`ssh2_sftp_*` for the most part).  These files add up to about a gig or so each time.  The bandwidth is throttled, so that's not a problem.  The problem is the ssh2 process eats up a ton of CPU and actually slows down the server during the upload.  Is there any way to start the ssh process at a certain nice level?  If php's `ssh2` functions create a new process (I'm not sure that they do), is it possible to find and `renice` this process once it's been started from within the php script?  Since the `ssh2` functions are not threaded, there probably isn't.

Basically, I'd like PHP's `ssh2` functions not to use so much CPU.  It seems like `proc_nice` will do this, but it looks like I may have to use `ionice` instead.  How can I do that?

Comment: I seriously doubt that they create a new process, so you would be better `nice`ing your own process before you start. Even then I sort of doubt this would make a huge difference - what server is this running on? I have never come across this problem before, but then I have never SFTPed files that large around before...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of the server .. I know it's Debian.

Comment: I shall have a play around and see if I can repeat this.

Comment: If you're not sure what the server is running, try 'uname -a' (as a normal user) as that will give you a clue. If it's Debian, 'cat /etc/debian_version' will tell you which version/release.

Comment: @pwaring `Linux dev 2.6.26-2-686-bigmem #1 SMP Wed Sep 21 05:29:18 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux` and `5.0.9`, respectively.

Comment: Ok, in that case you're probably running Debian Lenny. Regardless of your ssh question, you will want to upgrade to Squeeze at some point in the near future, as security updates for Lenny stop in February (plus you'll get PHP 5.3.x, with all the improvements that brings).

Comment: @pwaring I have nothing to do with that, but as I understand we're working on the upgrade.

Comment: @tandu I cannot replicate this on Fedora, but I do not have a Debian box to test with. Maybe your upgrade will fix the problem, also maybe if the server at the other end supports `ftps://` you could use this, since PHP has built in support for this wrapper as long as OpenSSL is enabled, which it presumably is since you can use SSH2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short look at the sources of PEAR::ssh2 shows, that the SSH2 functions are executed in-thread and in-process, so there is no real straight-forward way. Here are a two possibilities:

- If you are on a multi-process apache use proc_nice to reduce
     priority, then apache_child_terminate to kill the process.

  Use proc_open or friends to open a shellscript of the type

```
#!/bin/bash
read SRCFILE
read DSTFILE
nice scp "$SRCFILE" "$DSTFILE"
```

We use the latter for quite a lot of CPU-hogging tasks

Comment: Fixed your code formatting. There is a problem (bug?) with the markdown whereby it get's confused if you try and do a four-space code section immediately after an unordered list. Work-around is to do an explicit HTML `<ul>`.